# Como modificar link em código PHP

Tags: javascript, html

O trecho do código é esse :

```
<div class="menu-item" ui-sref="albums" ui-sref-active="active" href="/albums"><i class="icon icon-cd"></i> Álbuns</div>
```

A ideia era linkar em vez de ir para "/albums" ir para outro qualquer link que eu digitar por exemplo : www.google.com

Comment: href="aqui_vem_o_link"

Comment: Digitar aonde exatamente? Div com href que eu saiba não existe. Isto é algum plugin de wordpress ou o problema é com html e js apenas?

Comment: é um site em php que tenho e não consigo mudar o link desse menu que veio nele.  

Essa Div que estou falando eu modificarei no código fonte mesmo do site.

Comment: Continua dificil de entender, sem detalhes, vc esta sendo bastante vago, não tem como saber se a duvida é de HTML, de PHP, de Wordpress, de javascript. Como eu disse antes, até aonde sei `href=` não é um atributo de DIV e você também não explicou aonde que deve "digitar". Tem como explicar por favor.

Comment: @Henrique eu fiz isso e quando eu clico no botão nada acontece

Comment: Jhonatan, nada acontece pq href não funciona em DIV :/, por favor, lhe peço gentilmente que explique com mais detalhes exatamente o que deseja e exatamente o que vc tem, recomendo que leia https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, obrigado por compreender

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu modifiquei o titulo da pergunta, nao tem mais nada de Div a resolver aqui,  vc nao leu a pergunta ?  ler ela e veja no corpo mais abaixo que eu explico que estou tentando modificar um código PHP em um menu, direcionar o link para uma url.

Comment: @jhonatansantos não tem **absolutamente nada** de PHP aí. Se você quer ajuda, precisa, no mínimo, conseguir explicar o problema.

Comment: Primeiro, como eu já pedi, não use o botão "Responder" para adicionar detalhes, somo um Q&A e não um fórum, faça o Tour para entender isto. Segundo, eu já vi o código e ele não tem sentido, a não ser que seja um plugin javascript ou wordpress ou PHP que renderize as coisas, mas vc não especificou que plugin ou tema é este, não tenho nem por onde começar a lhe ajudar, você não esta informando detalhes essenciais. Terceiro, por favor, novamente de maneira encarecida lhe peço informe o que foi pedido: Aonde deseja digitar? Que tema ou plugin é este?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de diversas formas:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><div class="menu-item" ui-sref="albums" ui-sref-active="active"><i class="icon icon-cd"></i> Álbuns</div></a>
```

Então estiliza o elemento `a` com quiser.

ou

```
<div onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com'" class="menu-item" ui-sref="albums" ui-sref-active="active"><i class="icon icon-cd"></i> Álbuns</div>
```

e outras formas...

```
<div class="your-music"><h2>Sua Música</h2>
<div onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com'" class="menu-item active" ui-sref="songs" ui-sref-active="active"><i class="icon icon-note"></i> Músicas</div>
<div onclick="location.href='http://www.pt.stackoverflow.com'" class="menu-item" ui-sref="albums" ui-sref-active="active"><i class="icon icon-cd"></i> Álbuns</div>
<div onclick="location.href='http://www.x123VXG.dxy'" class="menu-item" ui-sref="artists" ui-sref-active="active" ><i class="icon icon-mic"></i> Artistas</div></div>
```

Comment: deu certo o ultimo código enviado.  
 muito obrigado cara .

Comment: Legal, seja bem vindo ao site, não deixe de levar em consideração as dicas dadas nos comentários, para que você possa aproveitar melhor o site. Boa Sorte.

Comment: eu fiz as alterações que vc passou ele até aceita, mas não aparece nada no navegador. ja limpei o cache e etc.

porém o autor do site me disse que é preciso compilar o arquivo. oque seria isso ?

Answer (score 2):

Links são utilizados com a tag **`<a>`**. Você poderia utilizá-lo desta forma:

```
<div>
  <a href="meu_link"></a>
</div>
```

Ou ainda com listas:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="meuLink">Item 1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

> Observação: substituir **meuLink** pelo link desejado, ex.: http://google.com